# GLM link function, variance Function, and dispersion for linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, link-function, dispersion

we were recently introduced in class to GLM's and I am still trying to wrap my head around link functions, variance functions and dispersion paramters. In particular we were asked re-write the linear regression using GLM.

First we specified the type of distribution in linear regression: $Y_i|X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,\cdot\cdot\cdot, n$, where $\epsilon_i \sim iid N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Since the link function relates the means to the observations, we obtained $\mu_i=\beta_0+ \beta_1X_{1i}+\beta_p X_p +\epsilon_i$, where $\mu_i = E[Y_i|X_i]$.

For the variance function we want to relate the means to the variances so, we obtained $\phi = \sigma^2$, and $Var(Y_i|X_i) = \phi Var(E[Y_i|X_i])$. Our professor stated that the dispersion paramter was one in this case, but I am not sure why that is the case. Is this simply because $sigma^2$ is a constant? I believe it was also mentioned that it serves as a location parameter.

Comment: I don't think you really mean to refer to "$\operatorname{Var}(E[Y_i\mid X_i]),$" because this is irrelevant (and in many applications isn't even defined).

Comment: @whuber thanks, I believe it wasn't written in this form, but I just wrote it like this. Do you have any links or references that might help?

Comment: Yes: we have many threads about this topic.  See those about [Gaussian responses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=glm+link+gauss*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10) and those about [Normal responses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=glm+link+normal*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10)